# Enable autostart of kubernetes service

Tags: kubernetes, service

Is there a way to get a kubernetes-service restarted in case the service is deleted or if it goes down ?

We have two services defined in a file service-zookeeper-group.yaml

On making a random check we found the service "zk-group" missing. (maybe someone accidentally deleted it)

```
zk-service  LoadBalancer  10.88.12.113   10.128.0.3   2181:32581/TCP
zk-group    ClusterIP     None           <none>       <none>
```

Is there a way to perform "liveness" check for the service "zk-group" and get this service started if it goes down ?

service-zookeeper-group.yaml

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zk-group
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  labels:
    app: {{ .Release.Name }}-zk-app
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: {{ .Release.Name }}-zk-app


apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zk-service
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
  labels:
    app: {{ .Release.Name }}-zk-app
spec:
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    name: tcp-{{ .Values.zk.port }}
    port: {{ .Values.zk.port }}
    targetPort: {{ .Values.zk.port }}
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: {{ .Values.networking.loadBalancerIP }}
  loadBalancerSourceRanges: {{ .Values.networking.loadBalancerSourceRanges | toJson }}
  selector:
    app: {{ .Release.Name }}-zk-app
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no Kubernetes "native" utility to check if a service exists and - if not - create one. If you really need this functionality you would probably need to extend your Cluster with a [Kubernetes Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/#custom-controllers).

You can recreate the desired state with the GitOps pattern utilizing a GitOps controller such as [Flux](https://github.com/fluxcd/flux) or [Argo](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/). If someone really "accidentally" removes a resource those controllers would ensure to reapply the desired state within a given period of time.

> "maybe someone accidentally deleted it"

Your specific case sounds more like a lack of monitoring and governance:

1. If a service is deleted accidentally - why aren't any alerts popping up? A simple probe test (e.g. via [Prometheus BlackBox exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter) or [Elastic Heartbeat](https://www.elastic.co/de/beats/heartbeat) (if you are using the elastic stack)) can check for the availability of services within the cluster.
2. How is it possible that something important like a service gets deleted accidentally? Who is working with the cluster and who really needs the power to delete/adjust service resources? I guess it makes sense to evaluate the roles/permissions on your cluster.
3. Consider activating the Kubernetes [audit trail](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/): If I would be the cluster administrator I'd like to know who deleted the service.